# Blocked by CORS policy: Request had a target IP address space of `unknown`

Tags: php, ajax, cors, private-network-access

Happening only in chrome. Working fine with other browsers e.i Firefox, Edge, etc.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.example.com/ajax-file.php' from origin 'https://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request had a target IP address space of `unknown` yet the resource is in address space `public`.

Already tried to add some headers recommended on other forums, still the same error.

Related issue: [Chome 102: has been blocked by CORS policy: Request had a targe IP address space of 'unknown' yet the resource is in address space 'private'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72448642/chome-102-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-request-had-a-targe-ip-address-space)

Chrome Bug Tracker Comment#20 - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1329248

Any work around on this?

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue: a not-cross-origin xhr being blocked by cors with this same message, but I faced the issue in Chrome and in Edge too(which uses the chromiun engine). I've been following a related bug in the Chromiun bug report forum, and apparently they solved the issue in the next versions 103 and 104. I'm waiting. I couldn't find no workaround for this, I literally stopped using the xhr and recreated the funcionality in conventional browsing way, in order to be able to release the application. I'm waiting for them to really fix it to put my xhr back on.